# Save ASP page into a different file format such as XLS

Tags: php, html, excel, asp-classic

There is alot of info on converting HTML table to EXCEL which is actually what I intend to do.

However, none of the examples work so am looking for a more brute force solution converting the whole web page.   I have noticed by renaming the extension from HTML/ASP to XLS the conversion is fine (good enough for my needs anyway).

So...

I have an ASP page with large amount of table data which by clicking a button I need this to open up a save dialog box with the file format as EXCEL only and not HTML/ASP etc.   Then the user can choose where to download it and open it up as EXCEL Spreadsheet at discretion.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: So just to be clear.  I don't need to directly convert a table from a button but just looking for an option to save the webpage as an EXCEL sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ASP all you need to do, is to create a link to the .asp page containing the table, and add the following lines to that .asp page, before any html tag :

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=fileName.xls"
```

Comment: That looks useful, is it possible to have this command in an onclick event from a  button on the same page that is to be generated?   Many thanks for your help.